# Tomcat does not replicate session attributes

Tags: tomcat, cluster, replication

I am struggling with configuration of session replication in Tomcat cluster. [Ramki's articles](http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/11/tomcat-clustering-series-part-3-session.html) about Tomcat Clustering helped me a lot. Load balancing and sticky session works well.

SessionIDs are replicated, but only IDs. Session attributes are not, they changed only on primary node. Apache Tribes replication of full session is missing.

My environment: Oracle Linux 6.6, Tomcat 8.0.20, JRE 7u55-b13

**Apache httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel    emerg
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T"

JkMount /status stat
JkMount /* balancer

JkMount /uzel1* uzel1
JkMount /uzel2* uzel2
JkMount /uzel3* uzel3
```

**workers.properties**

```
worker.list=balancer,stat

worker.uzel1.type=ajp13
worker.uzel1.port=8021
worker.uzel1.host=localhost
worker.uzel1.lbfactor=10

worker.uzel2.type=ajp13
worker.uzel2.port=8022
worker.uzel2.host=localhost
worker.uzel2.lbfactor=10

worker.uzel3.type=ajp13
worker.uzel3.port=8023
worker.uzel3.host=localhost
worker.uzel3.lbfactor=10

worker.balancer.type=lb
worker.balancer.balance_workers=uzel1,uzel2,uzel3

worker.stat.type=status
```

**Tomcat1 (uzel1) server.xml** (other nodes uses increased port numbers, e.g. 8022, 4001, etc.)

```
<Connector port="8021" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8441" />
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="uzel1">
    <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8">
      <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
               notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
      <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                    address="224.0.0.4"
                    port="45564"
                    frequency="500"
                    dropTime="3000"/>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                  address="auto"
                  port="4001"
                  autoBind="100"
                  selectorTimeout="5000"
                  maxThreads="6"/>
        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
          <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
      </Channel>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
             filter=""/>
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
      <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
    </Cluster>
```

When new session is created, this is logged in **uzel1/catalina.out**

```
12-Mar-2015 15:56:53.540 FINE [ajp-nio-8021-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.sendCreateSession Manager [localhost#] send new session (6BB91945986B0B389849887109F97864.uzel1)
12-Mar-2015 15:56:53.542 FINE [ajp-nio-8021-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.createSession Created a DeltaSession with Id [6BB91945986B0B389849887109F97864.uzel1] Total count=1
12-Mar-2015 15:56:53.547 FINE [ajp-nio-8021-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.requestCompleted Manager [localhost#]: create session message [6BB91945986B0B389849887109F97864.uzel1] delta request.
```

Tomcat2 writes this to **uzel2/catalina.out**

```
12-Mar-2015 15:56:53.545 FINE [Tribes-Task-Receiver-5] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.messageReceived Manager [localhost#]: Received SessionMessage of type=(SESSION-MODIFIED) from [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 1, 61}:4001,{10, 0, 1, 61},4001, alive=193202, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={67 84 5 -55 -55 -93 72 -27 -88 19 109 68 117 4 -82 56 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
12-Mar-2015 15:56:53.546 FINE [Tribes-Task-Receiver-5] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.handleSESSION_CREATED Manager [localhost#]: received session [6BB91945986B0B389849887109F97864.uzel1] created.
12-Mar-2015 15:56:53.554 FINE [Tribes-Task-Receiver-6] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.messageReceived Manager [localhost#]: Received SessionMessage of type=(SESSION-DELTA) from [org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.MemberImpl[tcp://{10, 0, 1, 61}:4001,{10, 0, 1, 61},4001, alive=193202, securePort=-1, UDP Port=-1, id={67 84 5 -55 -55 -93 72 -27 -88 19 109 68 117 4 -82 56 }, payload={}, command={}, domain={}, ]]
12-Mar-2015 15:56:53.555 FINE [Tribes-Task-Receiver-6] org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.handleSESSION_DELTA Manager [localhost#]: received session [6BB91945986B0B389849887109F97864.uzel1] delta.
```

So second node knows about new session. However, it does not replicate it.

No TCP packet was caugth at ports 4001-4003 with

```
#tcpdump -nnq dst port 4001 or dst port 4002 or dst port 4003
```

Do you have any ideas what should be checked, dumped, examined?

Any help is appreciated!

Leos

Comment: Make sure your `web.xml` has the `<distributable/>` element

Comment: @Federico: Forgot to tell. Yes, this element was included in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

There were two problems

- wrong example application: Ramki's [example](http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/10/tomcat-clustering-series-part-2-session.html) index.jsp does not support session state replication
- container `<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"` has to be moved from `server.xml` to `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml` as mentioned in post [Tomcat's Clustering / Session Replication not replicating properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835014/tomcats-clustering-session-replication-not-replicating-properly)

Session replication works with Apache Tomcat example servlet SessionExample, accessible at
http://host:port/examples/servlets/servlet/SessionExample